# Empty Sudoku Filler C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program that fills in an empty 9x9 array with the proper values for a sudoku board. My validation method works as I've tested it out in a simple iterative backtracking approach. 
My current approach is to randomly choose a row and a column and place an appropriate value, I am also implementing backtracking through the use of recursion. Here is my solver function:

```
void solve (int board[9][9]) {

    static int counter = 0;
    int val = 0;
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    if (counter == 81) {
        print (board, counter);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1) {
        row = rand() % 9;
        col = rand() % 9;
        if (board[row][col] == 0)
            break;
    }

    ++counter;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        val = i;
        if (ok (board, row, col, val)) {
            board[row][col] = val;
            solve (board);
        }
    }
    --counter;
}
```

Now the issue I am having is that I never reach 81, my function terminates before that, I am assuming the stack gets empty and returns to main. Can you help me understand what mistake I am making? Thank you.

Comment: [The debugger is your friend. Use the debugger.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger)

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for that, like a idiot I printed out the board every time a value was inserted and used that to see what the issue was. Ill be sure to use that now.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/soryy708/Sudoker) might help. I did it.

Comment: `void solve (int board[9][9]) {` is technically like `solve(int **)`, so pointer is given from call to call, each `solve` working over the same board, so you must clean it yourself (like Nelxiost pointed out). In Object programming one of possible designs would be to create board as member variable of solver class, solver operating on that (not filling up stack with the same pointer every time). Some more notes to the code style: `for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)` - I would use `i <= 9` to follow human logic: "trying digits from 1 to 9". Rename `i` to `val` and remove `val` (less stack used).

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you for the suggestion on cleaning the code, really appreciate it. Hmm so the idea behind board being a member variable is that, since the class will be instantiated only once, every call on the member from that class will only occur once, instead of multiple times?

Comment: I don't know how to understand "call on the member". `class Solver { Board board; /* single instance of board */ public: solve(Board & board); private: solve(); };` .. in public solve you set the board member var, in inner private solve you access it, in all the depths of recursion. Actually unless you really want practice recursion, this solver can be rewritten easily in non-call recursion variant (ie. like `for (counter = alreadyFilled; counter < 81; ++counter) { ..solving... }` way, without calling itself). You should probably try that as next exercise.

Comment: That would of course mean you still have to store the [x,y] of previous depths, so for example in some `std::vector` adding/removing it to/from tail (index = depth of recursion = counter actually). See some tutorial about recursion, and how to rewrite it into non-call variants. It should be well described somewhere, as recursion is important programming principle to learn. As the basic rule about recursion says: **To understand the recursion, you must first understand the recursion.** - which sums it nicely.

Comment: @Ped7g Ohhh that makes much more sense, my apologies, I had assumed you were going to create the solve function outside the class. Yeah I did it non recursively first, I'm not the best with recursion so I redid it this way. Thanks, correct me if I'm wrong, so I store the x and y inside the vector everytime a position is found, and when no value can be given in a position, go back one in the vector as a form of backtracking.

Comment: Yes. That's basically what you do also in this version, but instead of vector you are using the stack, and the [val,row,col,i] quadruplets are interleaved with [return-address, board-pointer] (waste). And stack is growing in memory by decreasing stack pointer, so if you would check the dump of stack memory, you would see those values with latest call at the beginning of stack memory, while vector would have latest iteration at the end. It's quite rare to be in situations where classic calling recursion is "good enough" for production-like code, but the concept is important.

Comment: About "creating `solve` outside of `Solver` class". If you say that loud, it should sound weird => usually means you should try more designs. Also it sounds weird for Solver to contain board (as the *main* board inside app), having just reference to original and creating working copy sounds more logical. In OOP there are always many possibilities, but you should often check your design by "who's owning what" and "who's responsible for what" (and has all it needs for it at hand), those should naturally correlate with the name of the classes. Often takes several tries to get it right.

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you for the last comment, I really do need to work on my OOP skills, my intro to OOP class didn't help too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to fill in a Sudoku grid with appropriate values, you eventually end up in deadlocks : situations where the cell you are trying to find a value for cannot be filled in without breaking Sudoku rules. As a simple example, consider a grid where the first row is `[x, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and the first column is `[x, 1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. x cannot be filled in, but all of the other values follow the rules.

In your case, when a deadlock happens, the `ok` condition isn't fulfilled by any of the values from 1 to 9 and the execution goes back one layer of recursion, to the previous cell, where a value has already been chosen. There, the function tries the next possible value.

In the case of a deadlock on a cell that has had a value (that is, a multiple-level deadlock), the execution goes back one layer of recursion again, but the value is still there. That causes subsequent `ok` conditions to fail when they should succeed, because of these "ghost" values. The problem doesn't occur for a simple deadlock because the value stays 0.

After the `for` loop, you need to set the value of `board[row][col]` back to 0.

Comment: Hmm thats very interesting, in the case you presented, you would just go back to the previous box which was filled and increment its value till you find a correct number, correct? I thought that since I was using recursion, once the function terminates it would go back to its previous recursive call and start from there, so it would automatically backtrack, am I wrong with that understanding?

Comment: @SyedSharukChowdhury My bad, I completely missed the problem. Edited.

Comment: @SyedSharukChowdhury the wikipedia [entry on backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) uses sudoku as an example and I think it gives some pseudocode. Nope. But it does link to a [sudoku solver entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms) which does.  This is wikipedia so it could have been edited to contain batsmurph fantasy, but still worth a look.

Comment: @Nelxiost Thank you so much, that worked out. It didn't even hit me that a situation like that could occur, my program works fine now. One question, instead of randomizing it, how can I get a similar output?

Comment: @SyedSharukChowdhury What do you mean ? You can fill in the board in any order. You will get different solutions depending on the order, but you will get one no matter what you choose.

Comment: @SyedSharukChowdhury you can search for the first field with 0. Order is not important. For proper Sudoku puzzle there should be only one solution possible, so no matter how you fill it up by brute force, it will lead to that one. For a more clever solver you should do something completely different, like firstly evaluation possible digits for each field, then filling up fields with only 1 option, updating the lists, and do some backtracking only when 2+ options fields are available.

Comment: @Nelxiost What I meant was is there a particular way to fill an empty board without going purely column by column and row by row, a more organized form of the random idea. I ask this because my program works, but there are times when it takes too long to give back a solution due to all the needed backtracking.

Comment: @Ped7g Hmm thats an interesting idea thank you. How would I go about that on an empty board, as the first box would be 0, and then it would go on a column by column, row by row order.

Comment: @SyedSharukChowdhury First off, choosing a specific order will be faster (albeit not much, I guess) than what you are doing now, because of the way you pick a random cell. Other than that, one thing you can do is keep an updated list of possible values for each cell. If a list becomes empty, then you already know that you'll end up with a deadlock and you need to backtrack. That also makes picking a value faster because you do not need to validate it : every value on the cell's list should be valid. Moreover, you can search for alternative solving methods that might simply perform better.

Comment: @Nelxiost Thank you so I should create a helper vector to store the possibilities, and as the possibilities decrease, take them out. Yeah ill be sure to look around for more methods, this problem really has taught me a lot.

Comment: @SyedSharukChowdhury If you try the lists idea, be careful when backtracking. You sometimes need to restore some possible values that you took out before backtracking, but sometimes not (when there are other, older constraints on the cell). Since you already have a counter, you can keep track of when you took values out, and restore only the ones corresponding to the latest updates. By the way, make sure to mark the answer as accepted if it fits you.

Comment: about smart solver... You may for example consider `short rowDigits[9], columnDigits[9], squareDigits[9];`, a single digit being a bitmask `(1<<digit)`, then invalid digits for field (as bit mask) can be produced as `rowDigits[row]|columnDigits[col]|squareDigits[square]`. When set a field to some digit you update them by `|= (1<<digit);` for all three, to release it you clear those bits back to 0 (`^=...`), etc. It's quite common for board games to use bit masks in some way to speed up some checks of board (for example in chess engines 64 bits for whole board, like white/black-occupied field).